# Exact relationship between linear transformation and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over the field $F$. Let $A(V)$ be the [algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra) of all linear operators on $V$ and $M_n$ be the algebra of all $n\times n$ matrices over $F$. Let $\sim_1$ and $\sim_2$ denote the equivalence relations of similarity of linear operators and matrices respectively. Finally, let us assume that $B$ is an ordered basis of $V$ owing to which there is an isomorphism of sets between $A(V)/\sim_1$ and $M_n/\sim_2$.

Here $A(V)/\sim_1$ and $M_n/\sim_2$ refer to the set of all equivalence classes under the respective equivalence relations. The isomorphism is given by considering a representative $T$ of an equivalence class of $A(V)/\sim_1$ and sending it to the equivalence class containing the matrix corresponding to it, say $A$, with respect to $B$.

My first question is what characterizes the properties of linear operators and matrices which will be preserved under this isomorphism. For example, rank, nullity, determinant, trace are preserved. But what is the complete list of all such properties?

My second question is, whether it is possible to give some algebraic structure to $A(V)/\sim_1$ and likewise to $M_n/\sim_2$ and to talk of them being isomorphic in terms of these?

Comment: I don't understand "similar" if the dimensions are different.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: That was a mistake. Rectified now.

Comment: Doesn't the Rational Canonical Form give us a canonical representative in each similarity class? (So that the invariant properties are those that can be expressed in terms of that representative.) As to second question, wouldn't it be more sensible to look for geometric structure on the quotient? The symmetry equivalence relation has little to do with the algebraic structure of $A(V)$ so where would we get  any natural algebra on the quotient?

Comment: If $F$ is algebraically closed, then the Weyr characteristics form an equivalence-class invariant that completely determines the Jordan form.